# Q: Creation of Azure Resource Group Project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-resource-group

I am trying to create a new Azure Resource Group Project for Creating a Logic Apps Solution in Visual Studio 2015 however I am facing the below error mentioned in the Screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Any update this case?

Answer (score 0):

It seems a issue caused by visual studio instead of azure. You may have a corrupt install and depending on the order that dlls are loaded determines whether you see the error or not.

This is a workaround in the [similar issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/122720/unable-to-retrieve-the-visual-studio-service-iazur.html) that you could refer to.

> The workaround - which does not always work right away - is to Sign out of Visual Studio (This takes 2 attempts to sign out and remove the credentials). Then reboot the PC. Once logged into WIndows, launch Visual Studio - DO NOT SIGN IN. Open the solution, right click on the Deployment project; which may or may not trigger the same dialog error. If the deployment dialog is display, then i can add account and deploy. Otherwise, i must turn off the PC and try again, and again, and again, until it starts working.

I recommend you can try the workaround if necessary.Then you could report the problem and ask the [Microsoft visual studio support](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/support/#talktous) for help.